# Unable to load JS script via InnerHTML in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular11

I have an HTML string in the JSON, which contains some text content, an external js script tag, and an embedded js script tag.
Eg:

I need to render that HTML string in any HTML element of the existing angular component. But when I try to do it does not load the **external js script** and neither it runs the **embedded script** code.

Could someone please help with it?

Example of stackblitz :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dom-sanitization-eg-lrjmfb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Script in **index.html**

Check now here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dom-sanitization-eg-8p1ruv?file=src%2Findex.html

Your JS is loaded as well as the video.

Comment: yes, you are right. but as the data(scripts) are coming from the JSON, I am using it by appending it into innerHTML. But it is not working in that scenario.
Do you know any alternative? 

In Angular JS is works fine without adding the script into body/index.html.

Comment: have you checked stackblitz which I provided ?

Comment: yes, I have checked.

Comment: that didn't work out for you ?? If no, can you update your stackblitz and let me know what issue are you facing now please ??

Comment: No, It will not work for me. I have changed In your stackblitz. Please look into that. The main concern is it should be load from .ts file only. adding a script in the index is not suitable for my project.

Comment: @HarshPatel I don't notice any change in my stackblitz.

Comment: Sorry @KrunalShah, the URL is changed after changing into yours. please check it in the below URL. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dom-sanitization-eg-xapnuy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts